# Signed Distance Harmonic Means are Positive

Tags: inequality

Let $1>x_1>x_2>x_3>x_4>0$ and $x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4 < 2$. Prove at least one of the following inequalities do not hold:

$$1/x_1 + 1/(x_1 - x_2) + 1/(x_1 - x_3) + 1/(x_1 - x_4) < 1/(1 - x_1)$$ 
$$ 1/x_2  -1/(x_1 - x_2) + 1/(x_2 - x_3) + 1/(x_2 - x_4) < 1/(1 - x_2)$$ 
$$1/x_3 - 1/(x_1 - x_3) - 1/(x_2 - x_3) + 1/(x_3 - x_4) < 1/(1 - x_3) $$
$$ 1/x_4 - 1/(x_1 - x_4) - 1/(x_2 - x_4) - 1/(x_3 - x_4) < 1/(1 - x_4)$$

I was able to prove the $3$ dimensional version of the problem through case work and I have some trivial bounds on potential counterexamples, namely, $x_1>4/5$, $x_2> 12/25$, $x_3 > 24/125$, $x_4 > 24/625$.

Comment: Computer calculations suggest that the  claim is true.

Comment: @mtheorylord   You give $x_1 > 4/5$ etc. So you can prove the case when $x_1 < 4/5$ for example?

Comment: $x_1 > 1/2$ by the first equation, bounding LHS of the first equation by $4/x_1$ gives $x_1 > 4/5$. we can get the other bounds similarily.

Comment: @mtheorylord  Nice observation.

Comment: @mtheorylord  According to your new question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3686293/change-along-some-direction-is-positive?noredirect=1#comment7576692_3686293, if we let $f(x) = \sum_{i=1}^4 \ln(x_i(1-x_i)) + \sum_{1\le i<j \le 4} \ln(x_i-x_j)$, then we want to prove that at least one of the partial derivatives is non-negative?

Comment: Yeah, that's correct.