# Change along some direction is positive

Tags: multivariable-calculus, inequality

Let:
 $$f(x_1,\cdots,x_n) = \prod_{i}x_i(1-x_i) \prod_{i<j}|x_i-x_j|$$
Suppose all $x_i \in (0,1)$ are fixed and $\sum_{i}x_i < \frac{n}{2}$.
Show that there is some $i$ and a sufficiently small $\epsilon$ so that $x_i \mapsto x_i +\epsilon$ doesn't decrease the value of $f$.

That is to say, at least one of the partial derivatives of $f$ is non-negative.

After taking the derivative in each $x_i$ one gets a system of inequalities. I was able to prove the statement for $n=2,3$ this way through basically brute force. This doesn't generalize well though.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: @mtheorylord  Do you mean $\prod_{i < j} (x_i - x_j)$ in the expression?

Comment: @RiverLi, fixed. Dhanvi Sreenivasan, everything.

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck? See [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959).

Comment: @AlapanDas It is possible for the partial derivatives all to be negative. He is not saying that the function does not increase in any direction, but rather it does not increase in any direction along the positive $x_i$ axis, for any $x_i$.

Comment: If $n \ge 3$ and all the $x_i$ are the same, then all the partial derivatives are zero. (The claim that $f$ does not decrease as $x_i \mapsto x_i+\epsilon$ is still true, since it is constant zero in that direction.)

Comment: @LukasGeyer fixed.

Comment: @mtheorylord: Now the claim that the function is non-decreasing in one of the positive coordinate directions is a little stronger than the fact that the partial derivatives are non-negative. (If the partial derivative is zero, the function could still be decreasing.) This might be an indication that some method other than using partial derivatives might be the way to go here. Or maybe just that one has to treat the case where some of the $x_i$ coincide separately, not quite sure...

Comment: If some $x_i$ coincide the problem is trivial. WLOG we can assume $x_1>x_2>\cdots$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is actually not that difficult. Assuming that all $x_i$ are distinct and taking the logarithmic derivatives, we just need to show that at least one of the expressions 
$$
D_i=\frac 1{x_i}-\frac 1{1-x_i}+\sum_{j:j\ne i}\frac 1{x_i-x_j}
$$
is positive.
Now consider 
$$
\sum_i x_i(1-x_i)D_i=\sum_i(1-2x_i)+\sum_{i,j:i\ne j}\frac {x_i-x_i^2}{x_i-x_j}=\sigma+\Sigma\,.
$$
We have $\sigma=n-2\sum_ix_i>0$ by the assumption. Now we can use the antisymmetry of the denominator $x_i-x_j$ to write 
$$
2\Sigma=\sum_{i,j:i\ne j}\frac {(x_i-x_i^2)-(x_j-x_j^2)}{x_i-x_j}
\\
=
\sum_{i,j:i\ne j}(1-x_i-x_j)=n(n-1)-2(n-1)\sum_i x_i>0
$$
and we are done.

Is it just an exercise from some book or you really needed it for something?

Comment: (+1) Your solution is impressive.

Comment: That was clean. I've was stuck on it for a while, didn't think it had an easy solution.